# icinga 1.6.1 passive checks failing after we migrate icinga master/slave server to new ip

Tags: icinga

Excuse me as i dont have much knowledge on icinga but unfortunately i have been asked to look at some ongoing issue in company on icinga since we moved icinga master and slave servers to new ip.

All active checks are working and all passive checks are failing since then.

I dont know how to troubleshoot from here but looks like slave server is able to perform passive checks properly but somehow master server not able to get these checks data.

Pls suggesst

Answer (score 0):

Active checks in icinga are checks done by icinga. Passive checks is check data send to icinga. As such whatever machine sends the passive check data will have to be reconfigured with the new IP.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a distributed Icinga architecture (masters and clients aka satellites) then you want *all* checks to be passive in the GUI if the checks are run from the satellites.

So passive checks are sent to remote Icinga servers to be executed. Active checks are run on the master.